# Global GOPATH in gitlab-ci

Tags: go, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are building several GO projects on our gitlab ci and we have the following dilemma.

When building projects with a *global* GOPATH (like on local machines), the builds take too long as all the dependencies are fetched on every build.

On the other hand, when defining a local GOPATH and caching the folders created by go get, we get fast builds, but awkward project setups, where the project itself is not on the GOPATH etc...

It would be nice if there was global caching but gitlab-ci does not allow that:

> WARNING: /build/src/git.my.repo: not supported: outside build directory

Comment: Are you not vendoring your dependencies?  That would solve the fetch-everything-on-build issue, as all of the deps would be safely checked into your repository.  Vendoring also ensures reliably repeatable builds, even if one of your deps makes a breaking change or its repo vanishes.  Go 1.5+ added in direct support for vendoring, where anything in `<project root>/vendor/` gets treated as if it's in `$GOPATH/src` by the Go tool for any builds of that project only, so you don't even have to change your import lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with @Kaedys on this one. If you use vendored dependencies and cached your `vendor` directories you wouldn't have to fetch them for every build. If you aren't vendoring already there's a handful of [tools to help you](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools).

I have seen local GOPATH work too. I'm not sure exactly how you implemented it, but you can take a look [here for an example](https://github.com/concourse/concourse) of how it can be done. They have a local environment that sets the GOPATH to the project directory when inside the directory.